# Accidentally moved apache2

Tags: ssh

I was using filezilla to go through files on server, and apparently my mouse decides to drag a folder (at the time i didn't even know) and now I'm unable to find the folder..

My ftp was unresponsive after the folder was moved, and i could not access the server through ssh or sftp.

I used rescue mode and mounted my old server files in /mnt/.. But when I do locate apache2 it does not find the folder.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it is /etc/apache2 you lost?

```
find /mnt -name apache2 -type d
```

locate is worthless in rescue situations since it relies on an index.

Comment: ended up being the /etc/ folder.  Fixed, thanks anyway!